# Error Circular reference VBA from Function

Tags: vba, function, circular-reference

I am struggling with using a function that I've constructed in VBA. I try to use it in another sheet that the one I refer to inside the function, but I get circular reference error. Could anyone please help me? It is the first time when I write a code in VBA, so please be understanding if the errors are...funny.

```
Function Dividend(row As String, col As Date) As Variant
Dim Table As Range
Dim Blgdata() As Variant
Dim v As Integer
Dim h As Integer, var As Date

v = 666
h = 27

Sheets(3).Activate
Set Table = Range(Cells(179, 1), Cells(844, 27))
Debug.Print Table.Address
ReDim Blgdata(1 To v, 1 To h)
Blgdata = Table




Dim i As Integer, j As Integer


 'For i = 1 To 666
  ' For j = 1 To 26
   '      Debug.Print Blgdata(i, j)
    '     If Blgdata(i, j + 1) = 0 Then
     '   Exit For
      '
       '  End If

    'Next j
 'Next i


 For i = 1 To v Step 7
    If Blgdata(i, 1) = row Then
                                  For j = 3 To h

                                  var = Blgdata(i + 1, j)
                                  'Debug.Print var

                                  If (var = col) Then
                                  Dividend = Blgdata(i + 4, j)
                                  Exit For
                                  End If

                                  If j = h Then
                                  Dividend = "-"
                                  Exit For
                                  End If

                                  If Blgdata(i, j + 1) = 0 Then
                                  Exit For
                                  End If

                                  Next j


   End If

 Next i

 End Function
```

Comment: Which line of code produces the error? And is the above code in a worksheet or in a module (if sheet, which one)?

Comment: Unrelated, but `row As String, col As Date` in the signature, simply doesn't look right. In fact it's outright confusing - future you will be looking at that code saying "WTF?!" in a few months from now. A row/column would be reasonably expected to be a `Long` integer referring to a row/column index.

Answer (score 0):

My first piece of advice on writing vba functions would be to give your function a chance to do more than the one job you wrote it for. For instance, rather than your

```
sheets(3).Activate
```

You could use use Activesheet or better, pass the function the range upon which you want to act.

Same thing with your v and h variables, perhaps use the

```
h = inputrange.columns.count()
```

function so you can traverse ranges of different sizes.

All this to say that I can't really reproduce or test your circular reference error because it is written to only work on your specific worksheet, which I don't have.

As a generic piece of advice, if you actually want a circular reference (as one would in a problem that requires an iterative solution) you can check the [enable iterative calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXpZ8.png) checkbox and it will allow the circular reference.

Good Luck,

Edgar.